# A problem on calculus and integration and need some clarification on that point

Tags: calculus, continuity

So I have just started learning some calculus and I came across this problem. I have spent 1 hr on it and I haven't been able to come up with any idea so as to what is going on in this problem. I did expand it using **Linear diffrential equation** but after the **integration**, I could not understand what was happening.

I'd be glad if some one could tell me what is happening here. *Please don't solve this*. I just want to understand this problem. Is this related to increasing or decreasing functions?

**Note**: This is a multiple choice question!!!

Let $f,g:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be continous funtions.

Let h(x) be a  solution of $\frac {dy}{dx}  + f(x)\times y = g(x)$ with $h(0)=c$

And let $p(x)$ be a solution of $\frac {dy}{dx}  + f(x)\times y ≥ g(x)$ with  $p(0) = c$

then:

a) $p(1)≥h(1)$

b) $g'(x) +f'(x) > h(x)$

c) $g'(x) ≥ h(x)$

d) $f(x) +g'(x) < h(x)$

Comment: Note;  I reformatted your post fairly heavily.  Please check to make sure I didn't change your intent.

Comment: Just to say, if we choose $f(x)=0,\,g(x)=1,\, c=0$ then we deduce that $h(x)=x$.  But then $c)$ reads $0≥x$ so something seems off.

Comment: Nah it looks even cooler now actually this is a multible choice question i couldn't understand what was going on here thats all BTW the answer is a) bit,any clue why but not the direct solution would be heavily appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your post to show that this is a multiple choice question.  I assumed you had to demonstrate all these properties.  Otherwise, i suggest trying a few examples to get a sense of how $h,p$ can be related.